# Lua initializing tables

Tags: lua, initialization, lua-table

In Lua when I created a table the following way...

```
test={}
test = { x=5 , y = test.x}

print(test.y)
```

I expected that test.y would be 5, it is not. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Programming in Lua, 2<sup>nd</sup> ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8590379825), page 23, chapter *3.6 Table Constructors*:

> ... That is, all tables are created equal; constructors affect only their initialization.
>   Every time Lua evaluates a constructor, it creates and initializes a new table. ...

So, the table constructor `{ x=5 , y = test.x }` first creates a new table object, which, after fully being evaluated (!) gets assigned to name `test`.

This is what more or less happens in your code:

```
test = {}
TEMP_TABLE = { x=5 , y=test.x } --> x=5, y=nil
test = TEMP_TABLE
```

Comment: SO even has Lua syntax highlighting! :)

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. Lua is really growing on me quickly. I mean as some one who`s re-visioning skills amount to lots of folders with the name stuff nested in each other.

Comment: @Doodle, thanks. Yeah, it's a cute little language with some powerful features.

Comment: @Bart Kiers, I am not sure if I would call tables of tables of tables of pointers to tables cute but it does make me all warm and fuzzy inside.

Comment: @Doodle, agreed. By "cute", I meant the small/simple syntax of it.

Comment: Indeed, I do agree, I was just being cute XD

Answer (score 2):

That's simply because test.x only exists after tat statement has been executed. So this would work:

```
test={}
test.x=5
test.y=test.x
```

so where you do

```
test={x=5,y=test.x}
```

you actually replace the table you generated with `t={}` with a new one, and take the value of the key x in the old one, which is nil.